# Is there a better way to generate conditional sql than appending the sql string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an ajax search function on a site which can filter and display tasks. I may want to see my tasks and others tasks, or just my tasks, or just others tasks.

I append the sql string abased on the parameters passed by the ajax request.

On the server side, it would look something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333371/89211 (But obviously with proper sanitisation.)

Is there a better way to achieve the same ends as shown in the linked answer? I've simplified the scenario here. There are many filters which could be used in any combination. I can't imagine when using a searching and filtering functionality with a large number of options that this is the way the sql will be created.

Comment: Well, how *else* do you propose to modify the behaviour of a SQL query without appending strings with new conditions to it? The alternative would be to select *all* [or most] rows, load them into PHP, and then process them there. [do no do this, it is bad]

Comment: You could use multiple `WHERE` clauses, have a variable called `$mode` that's "mine","both" or "others", then use `WHERE ($mode = 'mine' AND (YOUR NORMAL CLAUSES)) OR ($mode = 'both' AND (YOUR NORMAL CLAUSES))` etc... - though the PHP string appending version is probably best in terms of cleanliness and readability

Comment: You can create for instance 20 different queries, and call one of them depending on which condition is met.

Comment: Yes, this is a fine way. I often build a list of conditions and finally join the list of conditions with ' AND ' to make the final, full where clause (rather than a series of `stmnt += ' AND <condition>'`)

Comment: @jmiloy Hum, yes, that would be better. Push conditions to an array, explode with AND. However, this makes it more difficult to use parameter binding. I guess you would need a second array to push the parameters to. It seems like it's getting closer to the functionality of some query builders, but now prefer writing the SQL manually.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid SQL injection attacks and maintain readability, you should use parameter binding.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Indeed, as I meant to imply with proper sanitisation. I'm not a hobbiest, this is my day job =]